# Parallax image shows at top of page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

For some reason I am having this  weird CSS issue but I have no idea on how to fix it.
I'm using the Materialize CSS framework.
When the page loads, the parallax element appears on top of the page, strangely. It disappears when the user scrolls. Here's a picture of what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExRPq.png

Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
  .main-container {
      height: 88vh;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-family: Lato;
  }

  .main-container h1 {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    margin-top: -15px;
  }

  .main-container h5 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  #search-box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    resize: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
      .parallax-dsp {display: none}
  }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<nav class=" yellow darken-4" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">mxious</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right side-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><b>Sign in</b> or <b>register &raquo;</b></a></li>
      </ul><a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="main-container">
<div class="parallax parallax-dsp"><img class="parallax-dsp" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/36/X7L5hgFXQZazzPaK3goC_14084990857_88cabf3b6d_o.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&s=d8812b80a08b8a04f4cf538f69a13b37"></div>
  <h1>welcome to <logo></logo></h1>
  <h5>Mxious is a social music discovery engine.</h5>
  <input id="search-box" placeholder="type an artist, song, or album name to begin">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your picture, I assume you want the parralax image to be right below the `nav` right?… which I think is fixed. Well, just do a `margin-top:` to the `main-container`, and it will put it right below the `nav`.

Another way could be adding a new `div class="top-fill"` above `main-container` and make it the height of `nav`.

Edit: Looks like I haven't answered all your question, but I haven't worked with that framework, neither too much with parralax, so I don't know how to fix the dissapearing issue.

Comment: I'll try the margin-top, one minute!

Comment: Holy crap I forgot that margin-top existed, thanks for reminding me haha.

Comment: Actually it did for the first 5 loads then it went bonkers all over again.

Comment: If you are on chrome, try a Hard Reload + Cache clear. Right click > Inspect Element > Right Click the reload button > Cache clear and hard reload(or smth like that), Im on mobile atm.

Comment: I was using incognito.

Comment: Mind telling how? Other people may have the same problem. Just saying.

Comment: Set the image height to 90vh.